# Add Facebook "name" to PFUser ["fullname"] in swift

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a registration/login method (from PFFacebookUtilsV4) that successfully adds a new PFUser object to my Parse database when a new Facebook user logs in. Within that method I make an FBSDKGraphRequest to get the basic user data (name, email). However I am having trouble adding the name and email to the newly created PFUser object. Here's my code so far:

```
@IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile","email","user_friends"],  block: {  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name,email,picture.width(480).height(480)"])
                graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                    if ((error) != nil)
                    {
                        println("Error: \(error)")
                        ProgressHUD.showError("Error occurred.")
                    } else {
                        self.userFullName = result.valueForKey("name") as? String
                        println("User Name is: \(self.userFullName)")
                        self.userEmail = result.valueForKey("email") as? String
                        println("User Email is: \(self.userEmail)")

                        // Here I try to add the retrieved Facebook data to the PFUser object
                        user["fullname"] = self.userFullName
                        user.email = self.userEmail

                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
                        println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                        ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Welcome \(self.userFullName)!")
                    }
                })

            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Welcome \(self.userFullName)!")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
            }
        } else {
            println("User cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: wow. a year and 9 months later i'm looking at this code and it's giving me a headache. i guess just smashing everything into one function works too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the user after you add the new data inside the Facebook request closure.

```
user.saveEventually()
```

Or any other save that you prefer.

Comment: Easy! Thanks so much.